# Reading geopoint from firebase firestore using geoFlutterFire

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully pushed data into firebase firestore and trying to get it back , but facing some issues with that . i would appreciate any help , Thank you

- This is my attempt

```
void getDrivers(){
     geoFlutterFire = Geoflutterfire();
     GeoFirePoint geoFirePoint = GeoFirePoint(latitude, longitude);

     var ref = _firebaseFirestore.collection('Drivers');
     var locations = geoFlutterFire.collection(collectionRef: ref)
         .within(center: geoFirePoint, radius: maxRadius, field: 'position');


     locations.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
       for (var documentSnapshot in documentList) {
         Map<String,Object> documentShot = documentSnapshot.get('geopoint');
         dynamic lat = documentShot['Latitude'];
         dynamic lon = documentShot['Longitude'];
         markers.add(Marker(
             markerId: MarkerId(DateTime.now().millisecond.toString()),
             position: LatLng(lat,lon),
             icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker
         ));
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'markers Size ' +  markers.length.toString());
       }
     });
 }
```

- This is an image of the firestore data
  [image]
- Error Image

  [image: enter code here]

PS : error points to this line : documentSnapshot.get('geopoint');

Comment: Do you get any error message? If so, please post it.

Comment: @TripleNine I have updated the code , can you please check it out again .

Comment: It seems like you are using Geoflutterfire which I'm not familiar with. The error message says that you are trying to access a field which does not exist. Maybe one of these documents doesn't have this field.

Comment: @TripleNine i think there is another way to access that geopoint ( it is datetype used by geoFlutterrFire) , i also checked their documentation but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

The `geopoint` field exists inside the `position` field, so to access it you need:

```
documentSnapshot.get('position.geopoint');
```

Or:

```
documentSnapshot.get('position')["geopoint"];
```